# Issue with variable scope in NodeJS, Express, Prototyping

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototype

File: MainApp.js

```
var reqHandler = reqire('HTTPRequestPostHandler')..
...
...
var httpRequestHandler = new reqHandler();


app.post('/', httpRequestHandler.handleRootPost);
```

---

File: HTTPRequestPostHandler.js

```
HTTPRequestPostHandler =function(){
   this.someVar = value;
}
HTTPRequestPostHandler.prototype.handleRootPost{
     console.log(this.someVar) //Error -> this.someVar is undefined.

}
```

I have these 2 files. The MainApp.js is where express is configured and various handlers for each endpoints e.g. '/'.

But when a post request occurs and the request handler (*HTTPRequestPostHandler.prototype.handleRootPost*) is invoked, I get a undefined error while accessing the variable *this.someVar*.

Why is this happening. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a scope issue, it's a `this` issue.

Normally in JavaScript, `this` is set entirely by *how a function is called*, not where it's defined. So what's happening is you're passing your method in as a callback, but since it's not being called in a way that sets `this` to be your instance. (The next version of the specification, ES6, will have "arrow functions" that have `this` bound to them rather than being set by how they're called.)

The usual way that `this` gets set during a function call is when you call the function as part of an expression retrieving the function reference from an object, e.g.

```
foo.bar();
```

That calls `bar` with `this` set to `foo`. But this:

```
var f = foo.bar;
f();
```

...does *not*. `this` will be undefined (in strict mode) or the global object (in loose mode).

Other ways to set `this` are via `Function#call` and `Function#apply`, which let you call the function and explicitly say what `this` should be.

You can solve this with `bind`:

```
app.post('/', httpRequestHandler.handleRootPost.bind(httpRequestHandler));
```

`bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to what you pass in as the first argument.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)